# How to rotate a 3D object around its center with mouse in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, 3d, viewport3d

I have created a cube. Now, I want to make it possible for the user to rotate it around its center using mouse. I managed to implement left-right rotation:

```cs
private class MouseButtonInfo
{
    public MouseButtonInfo()
    {
        prevPosition = new Point();
        isDown = false;
    }
    public MouseButtonInfo(Point p, bool b)
    {
        prevPosition = p;
        isDown = b; 
    }
    public Point prevPosition;
    public bool isDown;
}

// right mouse button info
private MouseButtonInfo rmbInfo = new MouseButtonInfo();

private AxisAngleRotation3D cubeRotation = new AxisAngleRotation3D();
// rotation of the cube is bound to this
public AxisAngleRotation3D CubeRotation
{ 
    get => cubeRotation; 
    set 
    {
        if(cubeRotation == value) { return;}
        cubeRotation = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(CubeRotation));
    } 
}

private void viewport3d_MouseRightButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    this.rmbInfo.isDown = true;
    this.rmbInfo.prevPosition = e.GetPosition(this.viewport3d);
    this.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
    var el = (UIElement)sender;
    if (!el.CaptureMouse())
    {
        throw new SystemException("Unable to capture the mouse");
    }
}

private void viewport3d_MouseRightButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    this.rmbInfo.isDown = false;
    this.Cursor = null;
    var el = (UIElement)sender;
    el.ReleaseMouseCapture();
}

private void viewport3d_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.rmbInfo.isDown)
    {
        double currentAngle = this.CubeRotation.Angle;
        Point currentPos = e.GetPosition(this.viewport3d);
        double offset = currentPos.X - this.rmbInfo.prevPosition.X;
        this.CubeRotation = new AxisAngleRotation3D(new Vector3D(0, 1, 0), currentAngle + (offset*0.4)%360);
        this.rmbInfo.prevPosition = currentPos;
    }
}
```

But I can't combine it with down-up rotation. I think the biggest problem is with rotation vector. It's simple in left-right case, however it gets unintelligible for me when X and Y axes are combined.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to manage rotations, moreover combination of rotations is by using Quaternions.
I won't post code here as it would be too long, but you should take a look at Helix toolkit (it's on GitHub).
They have implemented all you need, (i think there's a class "RotateHandler" and "CameraControl" that would particularily interest you)